# Pyinstaller script error when converting a python file into an executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyppeteer

I'm trying to use pyinstaller to convert my python file into an executable, but I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sr_gui_test.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "requests_html.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "pyppeteer\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
NameError: name '__version__' is not defined
```

I have no idea what this **version** variable is and how I should fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround on [pyppeteer issue #213](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/issues/213): editing the `__init__.py` as nonewind suggests.

In `pyppeteer/__init__.py`, simply add the line

```py
__version__="0.2.5"
```

after the lines:

```
try:
    __version__ = version(__name__)
except Exception:
    pass
```